# Ajax does not take all params

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a litte problem with the update. I have a couple of forms (over a loop). The script works fine with the first form, but with the others there is a problem.

```
while ($zeile = mysqli_fetch_array( $result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
....

$_SESSION['date'][$a] = $zeile['submit_time'];
$_SESSION['bes'][$a] = $zeile['date'];
<form id="upload" method="post" name="form">  
        <td>
        <input onclick="this.value='';" class="datepicker" type="text" name="date" value="<?php echo $date_bes; ?>"/ readonly></td>
        <script>
        $(function() {
            $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();
        });
        </script>
        <td style='text-align:center;width:120px;'>
        <input id="chk<?php echo $a; ?>" class="chk" name="chk" type="checkbox" value=""
        <?php if($check == 1){ echo "checked"; }else{ echo "";} ?>/>
        <input type="hidden" class="id" value="<?php echo $id_submit; ?>">
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;width:240px;">
        <textarea id="remark<?php echo $a; ?>" class="remark" name="remark" cols="30" rows="1" ><?php echo $remark; ?></textarea>
    </td>
    <td>
    <input class="submit" type="image" src="save.jpg"></td>
    </form>
...
}
```

my ajax_script.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
        $( "#upload" ).on("submit", function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

            var id = $('.id').val();
            var date = $('.datepicker').val();
            var chk = $('.chk').prop('checked');
            var remark = $('.remark').val();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'update.php',  
                data: {id: id, date: date, chk: chk, remark: remark},
                success: function (data) {
                if(data.success == true)
                {
                    console.log('everything fine');
                }
                },
                error: function(){
                    console.log('something bad happened');

                }

             });
alert('Job done');
});
});
```

and the update.php

```
<?php
$id = $_POST['id'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$chk = $_POST['chk'];

$cancel_bool = ((int)$chk) ? 1 : 0;
$remark = $_POST['remark'];

    $year = substr($date,6,4);
    $mon  = substr($date,3,2);
    $day  = substr($date,0,2);
    $date = $year.'-'.$mon.'-'.$day;

if($chk == "true"){
$chk = 1;
}else{
$chk = 0;
}
echo "<br>";
echo $id ."<br>".$date."<br>".$chk."<br>".$remark;

require_once('config.php');
$link = mysqli_connect (
                     MYSQL_HOST, 
                     MYSQL_USER, 
                     MYSQL_PASSWORD, 
                     MYSQL_DATABASE
                    );

if(!$link){
    die('connection failed: ' .mysql_error());
}
$sql = "UPDATE table1
SET date = '$date', cancel_bool ='$chk', remark = '$remark' WHERE id_submits = $id";
$result = mysqli_query( $link, $sql );
?>
```

With the first form it posts the following param by clicking on save.jpg:

- **chk**   true
- **date**   16.04.2014
- **id**    1396002713.9412
- **remark**   mytext_one

second form:

- **chk**
- **date**   08.04.2014
- **remark**   mytext_two

Where is the id?

Any help or idea?

Greets Yab86

[image]

Comment: I see only one form, and no loop... If you just loop this form, you'll  get problems with the `id` attribute of the form tag. Could you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) please?

Comment: Start with [valid html](http://validator.w3.org)

Comment: I am sorry. What do you mean with fiddle? I updated the script with the while-loop. I printed the id - there is no problem, because I see the different id's which I get from the database.

Comment: where is this coming from ? `$id_submit`

Comment: he means jsfiddle.net -

Comment: I have no experience with jsfiddle.net. :-( I posted the td-tags to show you the variables.

Comment: I tried to put the code in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kLQKv/ . But I did not know where to put my update.php-file.